# Problems on updating an var from a select form in Lift

Tags: scala, lift

I need to update a var at my code from a select form. I also want to sent a message to my server every time the var is updated. I first tryied to do:

```
def b = ajaxSelect(list,default, b => {v=b;FormServer ! Update();Noop})
```

The messages are being set, but my var isn't updated. I've seen some exemples saying that I should use SetValById instead:

```
def b = ajaxSelect(list,default, b => {SetValById("v","");FormServer ! Update();Noop})
```

But it also doesn't work. In fact, I just can't use SetValById, even with simpler examples:

```
def b = ajaxSelect(list,default, b => {SetValById("v","");})
```

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used ajaxSelect, rather ajaxSelectObj, and this work for me

```
def b = SHtml.ajaxSelectObj[String](list, default, onSelect _)
```

with

```
private def onSelect(value:String) : JsCmd = {
  v=value
  Noop
}
```

Maybe you've got an issue of name collision; using b might confuse the compiler ?